MudDataGrid inside MudDialog
Ok, I have problem with MudDataGrid being inside MudDialog.
My data grid has many items, so it's taller than the dialog. But I would like to get the outcome that Dialog doesn't show any scroll. So that grid is only scrollable, something like that:
|--------------------|
|                    |
|  |--------------|  |
|  | this is grid |  |
|  |              |  |
|  |              |  |
|  |              |  |
|  |              |  |
|  |              |  |
|  |------------- |  |
|                    |
|  Other stuff       |
----------------------
|        OK   Cancel |
----------------------

The first thing is dialog itself - without any scrolls
Then we have grid with scroll
Then some other stuff (MudText)
And the grid footer with OK and Cancel buttons.
I am struggling with this grid for couple of hours now. But I am from backend, not front, so I need some help with that.

Ask MudBlazor on their GitHub Site -> issues?

Something like this?

There's built-in DialogOptions that you can use to configure the dialog.
In this example, I set the MaxWidth and FullWidth in DialogOptions. There's also options to fullscreen the dialog in the examples
<MudButton OnClick="OpenDialogAsync" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary">
    Datagrid + Dialog
</MudButton>

@code {
    private readonly DialogOptions _maxWidth = new() { MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Medium, FullWidth = true };

    private async Task OpenDialogAsync()
    {
        var dialog = await DialogService.ShowAsync<DialogScrollableExample_Dialog>("My Title",_maxWidth);
        var result = await dialog.Result;
    }
}

Then in the Dialog, I give the MudDataGrid a Height and a FixedHeader so that the headers are fixed when scrolling. There's also a FixedFooter.
Also, applied an overflow:hidden on MudDialog.ContentStyle to hide the scroll from the dialog.
<MudDialog Style="outline:1px solid green;" ContentStyle="outline:1px solid red;overflow:hidden;">
    <TitleContent>
        <MudSlider T="int" Max="100" Min="20" @bind-Value="@_height" Variant="Variant.Outlined">DataGrid Height Slider = @_height</MudSlider>
    </TitleContent>
    <DialogContent>
        <MudDataGrid Items="@Elements.Take(100)" FixedHeader="true" Height=@($"{_height}vh;")>
            <Columns>
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
            </Columns>
        </MudDataGrid>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

Demo  MudBlazor Snippet

Thanks, it works. But how come height givent in percents doesn't work, only in vh?

Because % is based on the immediate parent element. And because you're using a third party component there are a bunch of hidden elements that are there. You can use browser tools to see what elements you need to pass the height down from, however the main parent still needs a non % height.
